# SharedPreferences issue - Losing last saved value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I'm facing a strange problem, my app collects some data from user input and save it on a SQLite database. I also have a service running constantly (START_STICKY) that each 30 minutes checks for new updates from user by looking on SQLite DB. If there is new records added, then it will be sent to my server using an AsyncTask to upload data. To keep track of what records were already uploaded, I store an int value on my SharedPreferences. So, this starts with 0 value and in each upload I get the last index on my SQLite DB and save it on my SharedPreferences. If after start the app I sent 10 records to my server, I will save "10" on SharedPreferences and in the next update (after 30 minutes) I will select all records where index is greater than 10.

Everything works fine, but sometimes Android kills my service, probably for memory optimization and then the service restarts (START_STICKY) and app continues to work. Only in this scenario sometimes I'm loosing last saved value on SharedPreferences and since I'm using this value as a reference to select and upload new records to my server, my app is sending duplicate information when it happens...
I changed the way I save the int value on SharedPreferences from "apply()" method to "commit()" because the last one saves information directly on file but the problem isn't solved.

Any idea on how to deal with this problem or other approach will be welcome.

My SharedPreferences class looks like this:

```
public class MySharedPreferences {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    public MySharedPreferences(Context context) {
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("com.mypackage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setIndex(int n) {
        //sharedPref.edit().putInt("index", n).apply();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("index", n);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return sharedPref.getInt("index", 0);
    }
}
```

My SharedPreferences object is istantiated on Service onCreate method:

```
MySharedPreferences mySharedPref = new MySharedPreferences(context);
```

This is an example of my AsyncTask that runs inside my Service:

```
private class UpdateData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            String response = utils.postDataHttps("https://my_url.com", params);
            if (response.equals("OK")) {
                // Access SQLite DB and select last index
                // by using this query: SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
                int lastIndex = myDb.getLastIndex(); 
                // Set last index on SharedPreferences:
                mySharedPref.setIndex(lastIndex);
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "UpdateData.doInBackground() - Exception: " + e.getMessage() + "\n" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a new research on SO I found this post: [User settings saved in SharedPreferences removed or lost between reloads of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955799/user-settings-saved-in-sharedpreferences-removed-or-lost-between-reloads-of-app/12816960#12816960) and since other options didn't work for me, I moved my reference variable to my SQLite DB by create one table with just one record that represents the int value I need to store. So, in the first run of my app I just return 0 if there is no record on table and after sent data to server I store last index in the table first row by using INSERT statement. Each 30 minutes I just check value stored in this row to decide which updates I need to send to server and after successful uploaded data I store the last index on my int variable reference again by using an UPDATE statement.

Maybe this isn't the smartest solution but it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you are not cleaning your sharedpreference data after ondestroy?

**Updated**
Try to use the context of your Application instead the context of your activity.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not cleaning the values. I'm just loosing the last update after app restart, the previous updated values are still there, the value is never zero. But thanks anyway!

Comment: which last update are you lossing? from the database or sp?

Comment: I'm loosing the last updated saved on SharedPreferences. On each update to server I first check my SharedPreferences value to see what is the last index I saved, because it represent the last record from my SQLite DB I sent to server.

Comment: Let's suppose that my last index saved on SharedPreferences is 10 and then user inputs 3 new records, then in the next update to server I will select all records where **index  > 10** and save the new index **13** on SharedPreferences. So, the next update to server I will check for new records greater than 13... The problem is: if service restarts after I save 13 on SharedPreferences the value will be lost and return to 10 and then I will send the records 11, 12 and 13 again (duplicate) to server... I',m sorry if I'm not being clear, English is not my first language. @diegoveloperThanks again!

Comment: I'm tracking this problem from log my app generates and most of time when the data lost happens, just my Service are running in background, since after some user input I destroy the Activity by calling "finish()". What's the difference in using Application context and Service context, since I use the second one to instantiate my SharedPreferences object?
Thank you very much one more time!

Answer (score 0):

Save the `SharedPreference` at `Application` or `MultiDexApplication` class. Seems like when your `Service` is recreated, the 'SharedPreference`is being reset but I am not 100% sure if that is the issue.
But if you keep you value as mentioned above, the value will not set to 0 unintentionally. Since`Application`or`MultiDexApplication` class remains alive as long as your android app is installed in app.

Comment: thank you for your input, but I'm affraid this isn't the better solution. My SharedPreference value is not being reset to 0, the previous saved values are stil there, just last update are lost when my service restarts.